# why am i getting an execution error when using while to loop though an array? c#

Tags: c#, arrays, while-loop

when running the code below

```
int [] a = {1,2,3,4,5};
int i = -1;

while (i < a.Length)  
{
i++; 
Console.Write(a[i]);
}
```

I get this error: IndexOutOfRangeException was unhandled

An unhandled exception of type 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException' occurred in ConsoleApplication2.exe

Additional information: Index was outside the bounds of the array.

Answer (score 2):

You get an error because when `i == 4` you increase the number by 1 and then try to access `a[5]`, which is invalid element.

Answer (score 0):

Because you increment `i` before using it. When `i` is 4, it passes the check in your while loop and then it is incremented to 5 which is out of range.

Answer (score 0):

You are incrementing your loop variable before accessing the array.  In this case you must subtract one from the length to prevent an out-of-bounds condition:

```
while (i < a.Length - 1)   
{
  i++; 
  Console.Write(a[i]);
}
```

A better practice is to start the index at the minimum value and increment *after* the array access.  This will make your code more readable and maintainable:

```
int i = 0;
while (i < a.Length)   
{
  Console.Write(a[i]);
  i++; 
}
```